# How to install virtual TI-85

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I was learning some physics stuff [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/mcat/physical-processes/vectors-and-scalars/v/visualizing-vectors-in-2-dimensions?qa_expand_key=ag5zfmtoYW4tYWNhZGVteXJcCxIIVXNlckRhdGEiQHVzZXJfZW1haWxfa2V5X2h0dHA6Ly9mYWNlYm9va2lkLmtoYW5hY2FkZW15Lm9yZy8xMDAwMDAxOTY1MTU3OTYMCxIIRmVlZGJhY2sYAQw) in which I saw they are using TI-85 complex calculator. I saw a [link](http://sites.google.com/site/dkarasmath/tiprograms) in the comment box on how to install it, added by user but unfortunately it was for windows.

How can I install it on ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get install tilem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  Tilem - TI Linux Emulator.

> TilEm2 is a TI calculator emulator. It emulates all the Z80
>   calculators (73, 76.fr, 81, 82, 82stats, 82stats.fr, 83, 83+, 83+ SE,
>   84+, 84+ SE, 85, and 86) and all known ROM/OS versions. TilEm2 is
>   completely free, and designed for Linux (but available for
>   Windows).<sup>[TilEm](http://contra-sh.users.sourceforge.net/user_manual.html)</sup>

To download click [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilem/files/tilem/).

For help installing see [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 1):

to get TI 86 on ubuntu first download tilem 2.0-2 (amd64 binary) from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/tilem/2.0-2)

Then you will need rom for TI 86 which you can get from [here](https://jeroendoggen.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/ti-86-calculator-on-android/). Read the line " You only have to download this rom image" carefully, 'this' will take you to download rom...

Thanks to 'Jeroen Doggen'....

Comment: The blog appears to be offline now, but other roms are up at https://tiroms.weebly.com/