# How to install TI calculator

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504003/how-to-install-virtual-ti-85) question and I have downloaded TI calculator.

But now how after extracting the file how to install it.

Comment: I think you haven't read the answer properly there is step by step explanation given in answer as a [link](http://contra-sh.users.sourceforge.net/user_manual.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must install this dependence `libcalcs2` , You will find it at the bottom of [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libticalcs2-7), get 32bit or64 as required, Download it, open the .deb in software centre
 and install it.

I assume you have a tar.gz.bz2 file of you app already, put this file in your home folder, for easy finding, and extract it, if you have a gz.bz2 extract it twice until you have a folder.

Now ope a terminal type `sudo cd` and drag and drop your folder on the terminal, press enter to move to this folder, once you have this folder open in terminal (you will see user@pcname followed by the folder location on the left.

```
./configure
```

If there is errors tell me them exactly otherwise

```
make
```

If there is errors tell me them exactly otherwise

```
sudo make install
```

And you are finished, run

```
tilem2
```

For the default app or

```
tilem2 -r /path/to/rom
```

For loading your custom read only (roms)

[Here is the manual](http://contra-sh.users.sourceforge.net/user_manual.html#x1-110002.3)